# Register Open Generic Decorator with Scrutor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator, scrutor

I have a standard .Net core Api and want to use a Open Generic IReposistory and decorate that with a DomainEventPublisher for pushing out events to servicsBus after persisting.
However, I have used Simple Injector a lot earlier which I'm a big fan of. But now when using MediatR Im trying to simplify DI by using just .net Core DI together with Scrutor package for decorating.

**Problem is an error I get:
"The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition." from Scrutor when trying to register decorator in Startup (2nd line below).**

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
services.Decorate(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(DomainEventPublisher<>));
```

I have closed these generic classes/interfaces and then it works. But Im not good with that. I would to i the right way like I used to do in Simpleinjector, and register open generic decorator.

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

```
 public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    private readonly CosmosClient _client;
    private readonly IDataContext<TEntity> _context;
    private readonly Container _container;

    public Repository(CosmosClient client, IDataContext<TEntity> context)
    {
        _client = client;
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        _container = _client.GetContainer(_context.GetDatabase(), _context.GetContainer());
    }


    public virtual async Task Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await _container.CreateItemAsync(entity, new PartitionKey(_context.GetPartitionKey(entity)));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
      
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> Get(string id)
    {
        var response = await _container.ReadItemAsync<TEntity>(id, new PartitionKey(_context.GetPartitionKey(id)));

        return response.Resource;
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        var response = await _container.UpsertItemAsync(entity, new PartitionKey(_context.GetPartitionKey(entity)));
        
        return response.Resource;
    }

    public async Task Remove(string id)
    {
        var response = await _container.DeleteItemAsync<TEntity>(id, new PartitionKey(_context.GetPartitionKey(id)));
    }

public class DomainEventPublisher<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    private readonly IRepository<TEntity> _decoratedRepository;
    private readonly ITopicAdapter _bus;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    private List<IDomainEvent> _eventsToProcess = new List<IDomainEvent>();

    public DomainEventPublisher(IRepository<TEntity> decoratedRepository, ITopicAdapter bus, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _decoratedRepository = decoratedRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(decoratedRepository));
        _bus = bus ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bus));
        _mapper = mapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
    }
    public async Task Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        // Get all domain events raised by source entity
        var events = CollectEvents(entity);
        await _decoratedRepository.Add(entity);
        await HandleEvents(events);
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> Get(string id)
    {
        return await _decoratedRepository.Get(id);
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        // Get all domain events raised by source entity
        var events = CollectEvents(entity);
        var result = await _decoratedRepository.Update(entity);
        await HandleEvents(events);

        return result;
    }

    public async Task Remove(string id)
    {
        await _decoratedRepository.Remove(id);
    }

    private List<IDomainEvent> CollectEvents(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity is IEntity entityWithEvents)
            return entityWithEvents.Events;

        return new List<IDomainEvent>();
    }

    private async Task HandleEvents(List<IDomainEvent> events)
    {
        // if we ended up on this line we know that repository persisted changes and now send events to bus
        foreach (var domainEvent in events)
        {
            await _bus.Send(_mapper.MapTo(domainEvent));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to apply decorators to open-generic registration with Scrutor. This is discussed [here](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor/issues/39) on the Scrutor forum. This is due to a limitation of the underlying Microsoft DI Container. This is a limitation that can't be circumvented by Scrutor.

Instead, switch to one of the mature DI Containers that do support this.

Comment: Hi @Steven, I'm aware of that you are behind simple injector which I like and used for several projects sucessfully. My thoughts here was to avoid combining MediatR and SimpleInjector. Then we have to manually register all necessary components for mediator. But thats doable

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your rational of avoiding the combination of MediatR and Simple Injector, but there are other DI Container to choose from.

Comment: Just that we need to register mediator components ourself in SI, but saw that a ngt package could help you accomplish that https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR.SimpleInjector/

Comment: That package just contains a handful of registrations ( https://github.com/haison8x/MediatR.SimpleInjector/blob/master/src/MediatR.SimpleInjector/ContainerExtension.cs) and you could easily remove the cruft and bring it down to 10 lines of code, or less.

Comment: True and we wont be able to avoid the fact that we need a DI container that can solve open generic decorators. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried doing it the old-fashioned way? Using Pure DI?

Comment: No, I have not given that a thought. Butt I will!